# Compile Latex file using a python script

Tags: python, pdf, latex, subprocess

I am able to use python script to create a LaTeX file, but I want to take that file and compile it, so it creates a pdf by using a python script. I have seen some things using os and subprocess but I really don't understand it.

Comment: related: [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/4279)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this out.

```
  import os  
  os.system("pdflatex mylatex.tex")
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely works, but do you know of a way to save it to a specific location by any chance?

Comment: You can use ``os.system("mv mylatex.pdf path/to/directory")`` to move the pdf to any specific location.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Alex: no need to use `os.system()` that runs the shell here. Use `subprocess.check_call(['pdflatex', 'mylatex.tex'])` instead. To save the result in a specific location: pass the appropriate command-line argument to `pdflatex` or use `shutil.move()` -- again, no need to use `os.system()` here.

Comment: @jfs Any chance of publishing that as a separate answer?

Comment: @jfs, why  are you adverse to using `os.system()`?  I've got no experience in either, and am trying to decide which to use.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCollins: it is not just my preference, the docs says so explicitly: 'The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system For example, 1- you don't need to worry about escaping shell meta-characters (even if you know what shell will be used) 2- `check_call()` raises exception if the command returns non-zero status: errors should not go silently by default.