# Convert Latex file to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, latex

I am trying to convert a latex document to a pdf document are there any commands in python by which I can do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085520/generating-pdf-latex-with-python-script

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pdflatex/ or https://pypi.org/project/tex/ could help you as well

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208123/11079284)

Try this please.

```
import os  
os.system("pdflatex mylatex.tex")
```

in addition, you can use `os.system("mv mylatex.pdf path/to/directory")` to move the pdf to any specific location

Alternatively, and more "clean" solution is without `os.system()` that runs the shell here. You can use `subprocess.check_call(['pdflatex', 'mylatex.tex'])` instead. To save the result in a specific location: pass the appropriate command-line argument to `pdflatex` or use `shutil.move()`.